# C# Comport - Possible Loss of Data

Tags: c#, wpf, serial-port

I have been trying to troubleshoot an issue and I really don't have any thoughts as to go about resolving the following problem:

I have a software application that is able to listen for a device that is capable of uploading data to a computer. Once this data is captured, it is written to a text file and stored for later use.

```
void DataRecieved(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   while ((bufferedData = comport.ReadLine()) != null)
   {
       uploadedData += bufferedData + Environment.NewLine;
   }

   comport.Close();

   System.IO.StreamWriter writeUploadedPro = new System.IO.StreamWriter(uploadFilePath);
   writeUploadedPro.Write(uploadedData);
   writeUploadedPro.Close();

   isUploadComplete = true;
}
```

I can establish, recieve, and verify a connection, and what I have programmed does indeed produce a text file of the uploaded data, however the data is contains is not complete.

Example:

```
%
N0?77??.5???3
G0? X3.??? Z4.5??6 
Z5.?? 
?3.5?76 
G01 Z5.?? 
Z4.9471 
X?.?3 Z4.???9 
Z?.???6 
?3.?? Z?.??? 
Z4.???? 
X3.7??4 
G?? X3.???? ?4.5??6 
M30
?
```

It has numerous '?' which either should be a letter or digit. I have reaffirmed that the settings I have for the comport (Baud, Data, Stop, Parity, Handshake, and COM name are correctly specified). I have also tried setting the ReadBufferSize, RecievedBytesThreshold, Encoding, and NewLine settings. I am not at all familiar with these properties and I didn't find MSDN to be to helpful on explaining them either.

If you have any ideas or suggestions as to why I am getting incomplete lines of data in my upload, it would be most appreciated. Thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your encoding. Try changing the [Encoding property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.encoding) to UTF8. The default is ASCII. In ASCII encoding, any character greater than 0x7F gets converted into a `?` by default because ASCII only goes up to 0x7F (127 decimal).

Though that might fix your problem, the better way to go would be to read the data into a byte array, then use one of [these encoding classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x76y3wky.aspx) to convert it into a proper string. The reason why that works is because you no longer converting the received bytes into a string. You're using the [Read(byte[], int, int)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143549.aspx) overload which doesn't do a string conversion. Its pure bytes.

Comment: While I went ahead and changed the encoding to UTF8, but still had the question marks littered in my data. I realized there was an encoding parameter/setting on the CNC machine I am capturing data from which I went ahead and changed and sure enough, that resolved my problem.

Thank you for your assistance!

I am lead to believe that the issue was

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem lies in:

```
while ((bufferedData = comport.ReadLine()) != null)
```

Try changing the statement to something like:

```
    while(comport.BytesToRead>0)
{
uploadedData += comport.ReadExisting() + Environment.NewLine;
}
```

Let me know if that helped.

Comment: I like your answer but I don't understand why you are adding Environment.NewLine. The ReadExisting will read characters as they are available including the line feeds and carriage returns.

Comment: Oh, yea, don't know why I included that.

Comment: Your method of reading from the comport captured the data, but still my data had question marks. I realized there was an encoding parameter/setting on the CNC machine I am capturing data from which I went ahead and changed and sure enough, that resolved my problem.

Thank you for taking the time to help out Janman!

Thank you for your assistance!